# How to disable filtering option for a QTreeView or Model

Tags: c++, qt

I am having a piece of code which deals with two QTreeView, where the items are added from left tree view to the right tree view. Here is a part of code:

```
MasterModel *model = new MasterModel;
leftProxyFilterModel *leftModel = new leftProxyFilterModel;
rightSelectedRowsFiletrModel *rightModel = new rightSelectedRowsFilterModel;

QTreeView *leftTreeView;
QTreeView *rightTreeView;

leftModel->setSourceModel(model);
rightModel->setSourceModel(leftModel);

leftTreeView->setModel(leftModel);
rightTreeView->setModel(rightModel);
```

Now for filtering some strings are set like this:

```
leftModel->setFilterWildcard(LineEdit->text());
```

This line is Filtering the contents of both the tree views, what I want is filtering option should be applicable only for left tree view.
Can someone help me to achieve this???

Answer (score 1):

If `rightModel`'s source is `leftModel`, then any filters you apply to `leftModel` will also affect `rightModel`.

Change `rightModel->setSourceModel(leftModel)` to `rightModel->setSourceModel(model)`

**UPDATE**: Or, you can add another layer of `QSortFilterProxyModel` so that your filter doesn't propagate to `rightModel`:

```
leftModel->setSourceModel(model);
rightModel->setSourceModel(leftModel);

auto leftFilteredModel = new QSortFilterProxyModel;
leftFilteredModel->setSource(leftModel);
leftFilteredModel->setFilterWildcard(LineEdit->text());

leftTreeView->setModel(leftFilteredModel);
rightTreeView->setModel(rightModel);
```

Comment: I can't do that, because rightModel is expecting data from leftModel, not model, so is there any way to achieve it with the existing way the source models are being set

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand. In your code, `leftModel` doesn't have its own data; it just "copies" everything from `model`. Furthermore, `rightModel` "copies" everything from `leftModel`. If you update `model`, then `leftModel` (and `rightModel`) will automatically update too. Can you provide more details about how you want to use the 2 different `QTreeView`s?

Comment: you guessed the first part correct, that 'leftModel' copies eveything from 'model', but 'rightModel' copies only the selected items from 'leftModel', not the entire leftModel

Comment: Ah sorry, I missed that. I've updated my answer with a new solution.